# Unable to send "POST" form, jQuery won't detect submit action

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, breakpoints

I am unable to send a form after I have clicked the button, I suspect jQuery is unable to detect the submit action. It is a form that is sent when jQuery detects the submit action. I used debugger to trace the click action to jquery.js (3.5.1) as shown below. The submit action function itself is a custom file code(I will also indicate it below).

After I used Mozilla to inspect it I found out that the POST (xhr) : status, transferred and header had no value.

If you know how to solve this problem kindly explain it step by step. I will be very grateful

jQuery.js Event Listener Breakpoint images:
[Breakpoint 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJPt4.png)

[Breakpoint 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ32V.png)

Custom JS code:

```js
$(".submitForm").on("click", function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var targetForm = _this.closest('form');
  var errroTarget = targetForm.find('.response');
  var check = checkRequire(targetForm , errroTarget);
  if(check == 0){
   var formDetail = new FormData(targetForm[0]);
   formDetail.append('form_type' , _this.attr('form-type'));
   $.ajax({
    method : 'post',
    url : 'ajax.php',
    data:formDetail,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
   }).done(function(resp){
    if(resp == 1){
     targetForm.find('input').val('');
     targetForm.find('textarea').val('');
     errroTarget.html('<p style="color:green;">Mail has been sent successfully.</p>');
    }else{
     errroTarget.html('<p style="color:red;">Something went wrong please try again latter.</p>');
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

The HTML code is here:

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" class="require">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="require" data-valid="email" data-error="Email should be valid.">
    <input type="text" name="contact_no" placeholder="Phone" class="require">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <textarea rows="7" name="message" placeholder="Message" class="require"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="response"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="wd_btn">
      <button type="button" class="submitForm" form-type="contact">Send a Message</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML to the snippet!

Comment: Most likely you're submitting the form from HTML, and a new page is loaded.

Comment: You need to add `e.preventDefault` to your submitForm button click - it's not clear, but that's likely `<button class='submitForm'>submit</button>` so will continue to submit the form after your click handler runs.

Comment: I have updated the question as you requested, I am really grateful for your swift reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. It turned out that the problem arose after the latest windows 10 update. It affected my WAMP software, the problem stopped after I uninstalled the WAMP server and installed the latest XAMP server version. The code works just fine now.

It was starting to drive me crazy when I couldn't find the error. A big thank you to everyone who replied.